# Sorting cells in rows to match respective column headers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to sort the cell value in multiple rows to match the value of a column headers.

What it looks like:

```
A B C D E 
---------
D
A C 
C E
B D E
E
```

What I want it to look like:

```
A B C D E 
---------
      D
A   C 
    C   E
  B   D E
        E
```

Answer (score 1):

On a second sheet, either copy the header row,
or display its values as references (set `Sheet2!A1` to `=Sheet1!A1`, etc.) 
Then set `Sheet2!A2` to `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!2:2, A$1)>0, A$1, "")`
and drag/fill out to the dimensions of the data. 
This checks whether the value of the column header is present
in the corresponding row in the original array (on `Sheet1`),
and, if it is, displays that value, otherwise it displays blank. 
If you don’t want to preserve the original data,
you can then copy this and paste values onto `Sheet1`.